# Store List of Realm Objects in another Realm Object

Tags: ios, realm

i would like to store a list of realm objects (RealmObjectA) in a property of RealmObjectB.

is it possible to get the RealmObjectB from the Realm and already have the RealmObjectA 's in the list property? Or do i have to manage them separately and fill it afterwards?

Comment: What platform are you using? BTW RealmList contains the references immediately if the object is managed if you had added them before.

Comment: I usw realm within swift. so i have to add the children first? and then add the parent? i tried to only add the parent objects and thought the children would be added automatically

Comment: I assume if you have an unmanaged parent with its list and it has children, then write the unmanaged parent to Realm, then I *think* it'll add both.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you create an `ObjectB`, add a bunch of `ObjectA`s to a list property on `ObjectB`, add `ObjectB` to a Realm, and later retrieve that same `ObjectB` from the Realm, that `ObjectB`'s list property will automatically have references to all the `ObjectA`s you previously added.